# Struggling on how to prove an inequality using the Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, inequality

Prove the following using the mean value theorem:  $ln(1+x)$ $\lt$ $x$, for all $x \gt 0$.

So far, I have tried the following:

I have created a function $$f(x) = ln(1+x) - x , $$

$x \gt 0$.

I have differentiated this $f(x)$ to give : $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} -1 = \frac{-x}{1+x}$$ which is clearly less than $0$ for all $x \gt 0$. But I am struggling to apply the Mean Value Theorem here. I have noticed that $log(1) = 0$ and so:

$$log(1+x) - x = f(x) - f(0) = x (f'(c))$$
for some $c \in (0,x)$ but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: You've made a good start! Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\ln(1+a) = a$ for some $a>0$ (I think you mean $a$ instead of $x$ in your last equation). What would that tell you about $f'(c)$? (And what if instead of $\ln(1+a)=a$ we had $\ln(1+a) > a$?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mostly done, we have that

$$\log(1+x) - x = f(x) - f(0) = x\cdot f'(c)<0 \implies \log(1+x) < x$$